# border сдвигает элементы

Tags: html, css

border сдвигает элементы. Как мне это исправить?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* top menu */

header{
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo{
    background: #008ce6;
    position: relative;
    height: 64px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center; 
}

.logo_img{
    margin: 5px;
}

.menu_top li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.menu_top li a{
    display: block;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    
}

.menu_top li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.menu_top li:first-child{
    margin-left: 140px;
}


.phone_img{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.phone_text{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #bababa;
}

.phone_text_number{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    color: #be1e2d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <a href="" class="logo"><img class="logo_img" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu_top">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="" class="phone_img"><img src="img/phone.png" alt=""></a>
            <!-- <p class="phone_text">Contact now!<br>(012) 345-6789</p> -->
            <!-- <p class="phone_text">Contac now!</p> -->
            <!-- <p class="phone_text_number">(012) 345-6789</p> -->
            <div>
                <p class="phone_text">Contac now!</p>
                <p class="phone_text_number">(012) 345-6789</p>
            </div>

            <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
    </header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы `border` не сдвигал соседние элементы, нужно управлять его цветом (в данном случае, прозрачностью), а не скрывать/показывать.

Также рекомендуется чаще использовать, распределять и выравнивать элементы с помощью `flex`, а не отступами.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* top menu */

header {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
  max-width: 1170px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  height: 64px;
  width: 140px;
  background: #008ce6;
}

.menu_top {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.menu_top li a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #231f20;
}

.menu_top li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}

.phone_text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #bababa;
}

.phone_text_number {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #be1e2d;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="" class="logo"><img class="logo_img" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
  <ul class="menu_top">
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="phone_img"><img src="img/phone.png" alt=""></a>
    <p class="phone_text">Contac now!</p>
    <p class="phone_text_number">(012) 345-6789</p>
  </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
</header>
```